# How to construct the Brillouin zone algorithmically?

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, geometry, crystals, software

For an Open-Source project I am trying to construct the Brillouin zone from the primitive vectors of the unit cell. I need to algorithmically generate the edge points of the Brillouin zone (and which points are connected) so that I can plot it and the user can click on these points to choose a path in the reciprocal space that can be used in a band structure calculation.

This feature is already implemented in [xcrysden](http://www.xcrysden.org/doc/kpath.html) but in the documentation it is not explained how it is done.

How can it be done?

Comment: The 'references' section of the linked page links to [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1093326399000285) where the abstract says, *In this article the program functions are presented with a short description of the algorithms.* Have you looked at this paper?

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks a lot. No I didn't look at this paper yet and it cites nice sources for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a small python program for creating three-dimensional Brillouin zones and surface BZs: https://github.com/CZJ2020/DrawBZ . Note that you need to input primitive vectors of the bulk BZ instead of the real-space unit cell, which is pretty easy to do.

Welcome to use the program!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/386462)